# Risk of online schools

Tags: careers

So I am currently working as a senior software engineer at a fortune 500 but not one of the ones known for it's software. I have worked here for four years after getting out of the military. I am pursuing a Bachelors degree in electrical engineering from the Oregon Institute of Technology. Due to my work schedule I can only do one non-online class per quarter. It is going to take me 2.5 more years on top of the three I have spent to finish at this rate. I have checked online and the University of Arizona offers a completely online Electrical and Computer Engineering degree. I would be able to finish this assuming credits transfer in 1.5 years. In the future will hiring managers look on an online degree in Electrical and Computer Engineering from University of Arizona differently that they would look on an electrical engineering degree from OIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always risky to give personal advice to people you know only from a summary paragraph. So I'll keep this generic and you can take what you want from it.

I have taught in the SF Bay Area for over 50 yrs. Job markets change; university departments wax and wane. Etc. Prediction is risky.

Some employers do use a related degree as a screening device. but @David isn't the only enlightened one who doesn't.

There can be huge advantages to personal contacts you make among faculty and students in a regular face-to-face program and I'm hoping the pandemic allows a full restoration of them soon. When appropriate, participate in local/national professional meetings, and informal local tech groups. (Some are temporarily on Zoom now--and useful even so.) Beware of getting so frantic with job and coursework that you miss out on personal connections.

Maybe check to see if a few UA credits can count toward an OT degree. Will your current employer look at certain courses as part of your job?

Some online courses are quite good. Fewer online programs are uniformly as good. There is heavy overhead to developing a really useful online course, which I believe contributes to the considerable number of online courses that are out of date or were never worth much. (This is my general assessment. I am not referring to the current status of any specific online program.)

By contrast, an instructor who has learned a new 'thing' can often start an
on-campus seminar that's exciting from the start, and then morphs into a permanent course that gets steadily better with each term's student feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As a hiring manager, I don't care. What I care about is your ability to demonstrate competency in the field you apply for. I have hired several persons from non-engineering degrees because of their demonstrated competence in mathematics, statistics, and customer service despite their formal degree.